# Javascript show/hide will not hide properly in Safari

Tags: javascript, show-hide

It seems to be a problem with show/hide in Safari. The site looks good freshly loaded. But if you click on the first link up in the left corner and than go back, the show/hide function doesn't work so well anymore and you get layers on top of each other. Note: This problem only occours in Safari.

I've used jQuery and here is my show hide code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  function show(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "visible";
  }
  function hide(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
 </script>
```

Link to site: http://www.smudesign2012.co.uk/

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you use jquery to show/hide the elements.

```
function show(id){
    $('.student').hide(); // hide all students
    $('#'+id).show(); // show the student with applied ID
}

function hide(id){
    $('#'+id).hide(); // is this needed? Why not do the next one and skip the parameter to the function?
    $('.student').hide();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This did the trick. I also added the hide command on document ready, so it will start up blank. Thank's again! :D

Answer (score 0):

try this 
and note the difference in **.style.display**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function show(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display= "";
  }
  function hide(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display= "none";
  }
 </script>
```